# How to Generate Symmetric AES Key from NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, aes

I need to generate a symmetric AES key from NSData value which created below :

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: initKey, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

(the initKey is a base64 String value.)

the question is how can i generate a secret key from the "decodedData"? (similar to android SecretKeySpec)

(i'm using swift 2.2)

Here is the scenario (in android) :

1- i have a base64 string.

2- i decode it to bytes array.

3- then create a secretkey based on bytes array length and AES type.

4- and finally define a AES cipher based on secretkey, to encode some strings.

thanks for help

Comment: An AES key is just 16 or 32 bytes of random data. There's no structure to them. If it's the correct length, you already have a key. If by `SecretKeySpec` you mean "using PBE" (password based encryption), then it completely depends on what parameters are passed to `SecretKeySpec` how to recreate that with CommonCrypto. There is no universal standard format for AES encryption. You have to reproduce whatever is being done by the encryptor. So if you're trying to match it, you'll need to explain exactly what is being done.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for comment, here's the scenario in android : 1- i have a base64 string. 2- i decode it to bytes array. 3- then create a secretkey based on bytes array length and AES type. 4- and finally define a AES cipher based on secretkey, to encode some strings. now how could you help me?

Comment: It looks like you're done. Once you've made an NSData, you have your key, exactly as you describe.

Comment: @RobNapier but i'm developing on swift right now! Is that okay?

Comment: Yes. That's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AES key is just 16 or 32 bytes of random data. There's no structure to them. If it's the correct length, you already have a key. If by SecretKeySpec you mean "using PBE" (password based encryption), then it completely depends on what parameters are passed to SecretKeySpec how to recreate that with CommonCrypto. There is no universal standard format for AES encryption. You have to reproduce whatever is being done by the encryptor. So if you're trying to match it, you'll need to explain exactly what is being done.

Thanks to @rob-napier